# Is UIBarButtonItem no longer supporting accessibilityLabel in iOS 14?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, accessibility, uibarbuttonitem

**Update:** This bug has been fixed in iOS 14.5

---

I have the following class embedded in a `UINavigationController`:

```swift
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let barButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Save", style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)
        barButton.accessibilityLabel = "Save meeting"
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barButton
    }
}
```

When running iOS 14.4, the accessibility label is ignored and only the visible title is announced by VoiceOver. However, on iOS 13.7, the accessibility label is correctly used. Has the UIBarButtonItem usage changed or is this an iOS bug?

Screenshot for context:

[image: Partial screenshot of iOS test application, showing OS status bar and, below it, navigation bar with Save button on right hand side]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I must implement a `UIBarButtonItem`, I always follow [these instructions](https://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/en/mobile/ios/development/#navigation-bar) to be sure that a11y will be stable and completely functional.

I don't know if this situation is a bug or a kind of regression due to the new iOS version but implementing a11y in the navigation bar buttons as customization is a perfect way to encounter no unfortunate surprises even if it looks like a boilerplate solution.

I've created a blank project with a simple view controller embedded in a navigation controller where a right bar button is displayed as follows:

```
class NavBarViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    
        var a11yRightBarButton: UIBarButtonItem?
    
        let a11y = UILabel()
        a11y.text = "OK"
        a11y.sizeToFit()
        a11y.isUserInteractionEnabled = true //Mandatory to use the 'tap gesture'.
    
        a11yRightBarButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: a11y)
    
        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self,
                                         action: #selector(validateActions(info:)))
        a11yRightBarButton?.customView?.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    
        a11yRightBarButton?.isAccessibilityElement = true
        a11yRightBarButton?.accessibilityTraits = .button
        a11yRightBarButton?.accessibilityLabel = "validate your actions"
    
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = a11yRightBarButton
    }

    @objc func validateActions(info: Bool) -> Bool {
        print("hello")
        return true
    }
}
```

Your right bar button displays *"OK"* and VoiceOver reads out *"validate your actions"* under iOS 14.4 and Xcode 12.4.

Following this rationale, you can use a **`UIBarButtonItem` as supporting the accessibilityLabel property in iOS 14**.

Comment: That does make sense for the custom view case. Have you been able to achieve the same results using the existing .title property? I do not believe one should have to create a custom view to get accessibility labelling working on this element.

Comment: @Amja: Implementing a11y in iOS often provides bad surprises with new versions: something worked, was perfectly read out and it doesn't anymore with no reasons with the same code when a new version appears.  
As you can't make any automatic tests with VoiceOver, you just find it out randomly and that's definitely impossible for me (especially with a11y) ⟹ that's why I very often use the recomendations of the site I mentioned  even if a basic implementation becomes a customed one that removes any unfortunate surprises.  
And, finally, that's a solution for your problem, isn't it? 

Comment: @Amja: "one should have to create a custom view to get accessibility labelling working on this element.", you're absolutely right but when you en counter such a situation with no corrections provided by Apple, you must find out an appropriate solution on your own and the cutom implementation removes this incomprehensible point that is really impacting the users. 

Answer (score 0):

Set accessibility of UIBarButtonItem to true.

```
    let barButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Save", style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)
    barButton.accessibilityLabel = "Save meeting"
    barButton.isAccessibilityElement = true
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barButton
```

Comment: What conditions were you able to reproduce this under? I tested this code on simulator and physical device using iOS 14.4 and VoiceOver/Accessibility Inspector still showed "Save" instead of "Save meeting".