# accessibilityUserInputLabel in UIBarButton

Tags: accessibility, uibarbuttonitem

I'm trying to assign the accessibilityUserInputLabels to a UIBarButtonItem for voice control to show a specific name; see code below.

```
     /// Button 
  lazy var groupButton: UIBarButtonItem = {
    var button = UIBarButtonItem(imageName: "FunctionGroup1", target: self, action: #selector(barButtonHandler))
    button.accessibilityLabel = "Goodbye!"
    button.accessibilityUserInputLabels = ["Hello!"]
    return button
  }()
```

But the button only shows the button's accessibilityLabel and not the accessibilityUserInputLabels.

I'm using iOS 14 and Xcode 12.4.

What am I missing?

Edit May 11, 2021: Problem has been reported to Apple; see [this](https://feedbackassistant.apple.com/feedback/9102328.).

Answer (score 0):

I had a [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66448316/is-uibarbuttonitem-no-longer-supporting-accessibilitylabel-in-ios-14) with `UIBarButtonItem`s not respecting accessibility attributes in VoiceOver. I reported the bug to Apple and it got fixed in iOS 14.5. I wouldn't be surprised if this behaviour is another bug that they missed (I reproduced your example in 14.5). You should report this :)

Comment: OK. I edited my issue and added a link to the problem reported to Apple. Thanks.